# Getting Landsat NDVI data processed with LEDAPS on USGS earthexplorer

Tags: landsat, ndvi, earth-explorer

I am trying to download NDVI values from Landsat on the earthexplorer. I read there were higher-quality NDVI series processed with the so-called LEDAPS algorithm. The page from the [LEDAPS](http://ledapsweb.nascom.nasa.gov/index.html%20LEDAPS) website mentions:

> To obtain Landsat-5,7 surface reflectance products processed with
>   LEDAPS atmospheric correction, you may now order them directly from
>   USGS via Earth Explorer: (select the "Landsat CDR" tab under Data
>   Sets).

I do not see however any Landsat CDR tab on earthexplorer?

How do I download NDVI data from Landsat on earthexplorer?

Is that dataset atmospheric-corrected?

Answer (score 2):

Go to this website: https://espa.cr.usgs.gov/index, and log in using your Earth Explorer username and password. Then you'll be able to submit a list of scenes that you need and have them converted to NDVI from LEDAPS surface reflectance. And since it's surface reflectance that they are based on, yes they are atmospherically corrected.

Comment: Thanks! Could yo uelaborate quickly on what the "scene list" is? How do I btain/create such a file? Thanks!

Comment: @Matifou A scenelist is essentially a text file containing all the IDs of your scenes. You can find more about it at http://landsat.usgs.gov/CDR_LSR.php